# Data from multiple mysql tables into one xml

Tags: mysql, xml

I need help. I got stuck.

I have 4 tables. They share the same 'sku'. In images table, there are several rows connected to one 'sku'. Meaning, there are more images that belong to one product.

Table images: sku, image
Table products: sku, , , 
Table prices: sku, price
Table images sku, image

I´d like to get this result in xml:

```
<rss version="2.0" data-websigner.1.0.7="true">
<products>
<product>
<sku>B291606</sku>
<skupina>PB290306</skupina>
<nazov>B&C•HIGHLANDER+ , charcoal, S</nazov>
<kategoria>Textil>Flisové bundy>Krátky zips</kategoria>
<farba>charcoal</farba>
<velkost>S</velkost>
<sklad>1</sklad>
<cena>24.02</cena>
<images>
 <image>1.jpg</image>
 <image>2.jpg</image>
 <image>3.jpg</image>
</images>
</product>
```

I use this code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT 
    sku,
    nazov,
    kategoria1,
    kategoria2,
    kategoria3,
    skupina,
    farba,
    velkost,
    sklad,
    cena,
    image
FROM
    products
INNER JOIN
    stock USING (sku)
INNER JOIN
    price USING (sku)
JOIN
    sparks_images USING (sku)
';

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


    $rss = new SimpleXMLElement('<rss version="2.0" />');
    $products = $rss->addChild('products');


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $product = $products->addChild('product');
        $product->addChild('sku', htmlspecialchars($row['sku']));
        $product->addChild('skupina', htmlspecialchars($row['skupina']));
        $product->addChild('nazov', htmlspecialchars($row['nazov']));
        $product->addChild('kategoria', htmlspecialchars($row['kategoria1']).'>'.htmlspecialchars($row['kategoria2']).'>'.htmlspecialchars($row['kategoria3']));
        $product->addChild('farba', htmlspecialchars($row['farba']));
        $product->addChild('velkost', htmlspecialchars($row['velkost']));
        $product->addChild('sklad', htmlspecialchars($row['sklad']));
        $product->addChild('cena', htmlspecialchars($row['cena']));
        $product->addChild('image', htmlspecialchars($row['image']));
}

    Header('Content-type: text/xml');
    print($rss->asXML());
```

The output I get looks like this:

```
<products>
<product>
<sku>B291606</sku>
<skupina>PB290306</skupina>
<nazov>B&C•HIGHLANDER+ , charcoal, S</nazov>
<kategoria>Textil>Flisové bundy>Krátky zips</kategoria>
<farba>charcoal</farba>
<velkost>S</velkost>
<sklad>1</sklad>
<cena>24.02</cena>
<image>
1.jpg
</image>
</product>
<product>
<sku>B291606</sku>
<skupina>PB290306</skupina>
<nazov>B&C•HIGHLANDER+ , charcoal, S</nazov>
<kategoria>Textil>Flisové bundy>Krátky zips</kategoria>
<farba>charcoal</farba>
<velkost>S</velkost>
<sklad>1</sklad>
<cena>24.02</cena>
<image>
2.jpg
</image>
</product>
</products>
```

Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

In your loop just output the image if the sku is the same as the last one.

```
$last_sku = null;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if ( $last_sku == $row['sku'] ){
        // ouput only image
        $product->addChild('image', htmlspecialchars($row['image']));
        continue;   // go to next in the array
    }

    $last_sku = $row['sku'];

    $product = $products->addChild('product');
    $product->addChild('sku', htmlspecialchars($row['sku']));
    $product->addChild('skupina', htmlspecialchars($row['skupina']));
    $product->addChild('nazov', htmlspecialchars($row['nazov']));
    $product->addChild('kategoria', htmlspecialchars($row['kategoria1']).'>'.htmlspecialchars($row['kategoria2']).'>'.htmlspecialchars($row['kategoria3']));
    $product->addChild('farba', htmlspecialchars($row['farba']));
    $product->addChild('velkost', htmlspecialchars($row['velkost']));
    $product->addChild('sklad', htmlspecialchars($row['sklad']));
    $product->addChild('cena', htmlspecialchars($row['cena']));
    $product->addChild('image', htmlspecialchars($row['image']));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I get the same result. http://xml.topgift.sk/output.php

Comment: Sorry Silly Typo on my behalf changed `$last_sku == $row['sku'];` to `$last_sku = $row['sku'];`